# Inserting 1 or 0 in Bit field in sqlDatabase based on Checkbox checked in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview which has a Checkbox Template Field, I am using C# code and basically when the user checks all the Checkboxes in the datagrid view I want to add a 1 or 0 into an SQL database with a datatype field Bit based on the checkbox being checked or not. Here is my code so far;

```
protected void SaveRegisterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            SqlConnection connection;
            SqlCommand command;
            int numRowsAdded;
            int id;
            //Boolean AttendanceChecked;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("AttendanceCheckBox")).Checked)
        {


            try
            {
                // Connecting to the database using the connection string in the web.config file
                connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

                // Create an INSERT Sql statement
                // To prevent an Sql injection attack, we add parameters with names starting with an @ symbol
                command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Attendance(Present, StudentID, LessonID) VALUES(@AttendanceChecked, @StudentID, @LessonID)",


                // Replace the parameters with the actual values read from the form
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AttendanceChecked", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = AttendanceChecked;
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AttendanceChecked", CheckBox("Attend
                //com.Parameters.Add("@Approved", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = status;
```

I am struggling to implement this part of my project and any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance...

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Which part?

Comment: Adding 'true' (1) or 'false (0) to Bit field in Database. How do I achieve this based on Checkbox being Checked?

Comment: A checked checkbox will correspond to a `true`. If it is checked, insert a 1 to the DB, otherwise a 0. I still don't know where you are having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
command.Parameters["@AttendanceChecked"].Value = AttendanceChecked ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: This is not working... Error message saying cannot convert 'Object' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection? My code so far checks each row in gridview then finds the checkbox in gridview and if checkbox is selected then I want to add 1 in the Bit database field. Thanks

Comment: Where in the world does `SqlConnection?` figure into that line of code? And why make it nullable (if that indeed is what you meant to say)?

Comment: @user: From what you pasted I would say that you would need to paste the whole method not only that part.